# How do I set the placement of graphs in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have this code:

```py
g = sb.FacetGrid(planes_df, col = 'OriginCityName', col_order = cities_top_ten)
g.map(plt.hist, "ArrDelay");
```

And the code produces 10 graphs in a row:
[image]

How do I get the graphs to be 3 in a row, with 4 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the `col_wrap` optional parameter to `4`

```
g = sb.FacetGrid(planes_df, col = 'OriginCityName', col_order = cities_top_ten, col_wrap = 4)
```